# Dynamically change the position of the div based on another div tag

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

i Have a icon related to it i should should chat bubble. if the icon position is not fixed then how can i show bubble chat relative to the icon. how can i change the position of the bubble chat dynamically based on position of the icon.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RcXVE.png)

```css
#logowrap{
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "SF-Pro-Display-Regular,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Helvetica Neue,Apple Color Emoji,sans-serif";
  position: absolute;
  right: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  animation: pulse 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
  border: 2px solid grey;  
}

.chat-container{
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 53%;
    right: 50%;
}

.chat-bubble-2{
  width: 170px;
  height: 56px;
  background-color: #6B8E23;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 58px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 27px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.chat-bubble-2::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 24px;
  width: 26px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #6B8E23;
  border-right: 2px solid #6B8E23;
  border-left: 0px solid #6B8E23;
  border-top: 0px solid #6B8E23;
  top: 100%;
  left: 74%;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin-top: -22px;
  background: #6B8E23;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
  
  
  <div id="logowrap"></div>
   <div class="chat-container" id="chatcontainer">
  <div class="chat-bubble-2" id="bubbleEndHere">I'm Still here!!</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here the position is fixed but if the icon changes how can i handle chat bubble position dynamically. Other than using media queries.I'm handling it by using media queries.any better approach? Please help out. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `#chatcontainer` into `#logowrap`, then set `#logowrap` `display:relative;`.

```css
#logowrap{
  padding: 8px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: grey;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: "SF-Pro-Display-Regular,-apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,Helvetica Neue,Apple Color Emoji,sans-serif";
  position: relative;
  left: 50%;
  top: 500px;
  animation: pulse 1.5s ease-in-out infinite both;
  border: 2px solid grey;  
}

.chat-container{
  position: absolute;
    bottom: 90%;
    right: 40%;
}

.chat-bubble-2{
  width: 170px;
  height: 56px;
  background-color: #6B8E23;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2rem;
  line-height: 58px;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 27px;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Franklin Gothic Medium', 'Arial Narrow', Arial, sans-serif;
}
.chat-bubble-2::after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 24px;
  width: 26px;
  borde
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="logowrap">
    <div class="chat-container" id="chatcontainer">
      <div class="chat-bubble-2" id="bubbleEndHere">I'm Still here!!</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

into